What Should I Do if I Found a Simpler Approach to a Question Elsewhere(Other than MSE)?
Yesterday, I came across this question and was trying hard to think about a way to evaluate the integral in a simpler way. I thought for about $15$ minutes, but couldn't find any solution. So, I thought of checking https://www.integral-calculator.com if there really was a shorter method or I was just wasting my time, and yes, I did find a much more elegant method that I could've thought of had I given some more time to the problem. Now, I regret searching up the solution. The question doesn't have an answer with this approach, but I don't want to write an answer about it since it is not from my own thinking. I have already left a comment under the question about checking https://www.integral-calculator.com.
Have I done the right thing? I would like to know the official etiquette in such situations.


If you find a solution that has not been posted before then write an answer.
If that solution was found with the help of an external website then say so, in the spirit of  How to reference material written by others.
Make sure that your answer is self-contained, readers should not be required to visit an external website. See also “Provide context for links” in How do I write a good answer?
Comments are ephemeral and can be deleted an any time, they should not be used to provide solutions.

In your case it can be as simple as “The following solution was found with the help of Integral Calculator,” followed by a self-contained calculation of the integral.
And don't just copy the output of the tool, but use it to present an understandable (and nicely formatted) solution.
